# What was the first programmable computer used in a flight-related role on an aircraft?

Tags: aviation-history, avionics

What was the first programmable digital computer, or device containing a programmable digital computer, used on an aircraft or spacecraft for a purpose related to flight? To use modern devices as an analogy, a GPS navigation system counts, but a passenger, or even a pilot, using a cell phone for non-flight-related purposes does not.

Comment: If we're counting spacecraft, maybe the guidance computer on Gemini spacecraft? That was certainly an early one, if not the first.

Comment: @Chris yeah, I would count that

Comment: The first digital avionic computer was not "programmable" in the same way we understand the term today. The F14 Tomcat used a fully digital flight control system but the "computer" did not execute any instructions. Instead they were blocks of digital logic (adders, multipliers, multiplexers, integrators etc.) that were connected together to calculate algorithms. So it was fully "parallel" (or rather fully pipelined) because it calculated all the numbers with each tick of the clock. It was digital though..

Comment: .. performing electronics operations/calculations on numbers instead of current and voltages (like traditional analog circuits)

Answer (score 4):

The Gemini guidance computer was the first computer used on a spacecraft. It had 159744 bits of memory, a 7143 Hz clock, and weighed about 60 pounds.

The computer was used to effect the first successful rendezvous of spacecraft, between Gemini VI and VII. It also allowed for more precise control on reentry than was previously possible.

Other navigation in Gemini was primarily done by reference to ground networks, but the guidance computer was capable of navigation if connection to ground networks was lost.